# Hibernate : could not locate named parameter [ ]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, query-string

I am facing this below error :

```
could not locate named parameter [ ]
```

My code is

```
 String[] params = {"PARAM1","PARAM2"}
Query query = session.createQuery("select paramValue from Table where paramName in (:PARAMS) order by FIELD (paramName, :PARAMS)");

query.setParameterList(" ", params);
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Please share your full code and stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must name the parameter

```
query.setParameterList("PARAMS", params);
```

You can see the blank in the error message...